# `npm install` Doesn't recognize aliases - can this be made to work?

Tags: npm, npm-install

I have a project that is referencing two versions of a package:

package.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "foo": "3.0.0",
    "foo2": "npm:foo@2.0.2",
  }
}
```

All well and good, but when I run `npm install` I get a ton of errors that say:

> **WARN** `bar@2.3.4` requires a peer of `foo@^2.0.2` but none is installed.  You must install peer dependencies yourself.

The code works, so presumably the dependency IS installed, but it's just NPM's installer not seeing that "hey there's an alias in play here" - is there a way to fix this?